# need help on regex when using a quantifier after a group

Tags: regex, regex-group

I would like to match either of the strings - `abc` or `abc*` or `abc?` or `abc{abc}`.The following `.*?(\?|\*|\{.*?\})` regex matches all the above except `abc`. Even `.*?(\?|\*|\{.*?\})?` does not work.

Any help will be appreciated. (I am using java)

Comment: `.*?(\?|\*|\{.*?\})?` trivially does what you ask but probably also many things you didn't ask. The `.*` wildcard will match any string so you need to clarify what it should not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the below pattern help?

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/XtEPSe/2

**Pattern:** `.+?(\?|\*|\{.*?\}|$)|(?:^$)`

**Detail:**

- Changed `.*?` to `.+?`. To match empty string added a alternate `^$` at the end. Plese remove it if it is not required.
- Added an alternate `$` to match `abc`
- The capture group 1 should give you the required characters.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can you elaborate more o $, I have only see it being used as end of line. What does it do when used inside a group ?

Comment: @murtaza52, nothing special it matches end of string here as well. For eg, in the case of `abc`, 1st captured group will be present and empty. Based on your string, I am assuming you will do further processing on capture group 1.

Answer (score 2):

Using `.*?` is optional, and all the options in the group are also optional which would match on multiple positions and also an empty string.

What you might do is make the pattern a bit more specific in matching for example word characters `\w+` to match `abc` before the alternation, and shorted the alternation itself a bit using a character class and for the curly braces a negated character class to match what is in between.

```
\w+(?:[*?]|{[^{}]*})?
```

In parts

- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars (Using `.*?`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[*?]` Match either `*` `?`
  - `|` Or
  - `{[^{}]*}` Match from `{`..`}`
- `)?` Close the group and make it optional

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EVvL42/1)

Comment: thanks for the answer. What does `{[^{}]*}` do ? I have only see the curly braces being used as quantifier ex {4}.

Comment: @murtaza52 This part `{[^{}]*}` matches `{` and then 0 or more occurrences of any char except either `{` or `}` and then matches the first closing `}` So it matches from an  opening curly brace till a closing curly brace.

Comment: @murtaza52 Do you also want to match empty strings and strings like `}{{{`?